# Create Android Forms Through JSON from a WebAPI Call

Tags: android, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, android-studio-2.1

I am an ASP.NET Developer and I have a working mvc application that I want to accept inputs from an android application. Currently I am in the process of studying basic android development and I want to know if I am in the right track.
 Right now, I exposed an API GET method from my mvc app, which supplies this json format: (I can shape it if needed)

```
[
  {"Display":"Name", "Type": "Text"},
  {"Display":"Age", "Type": "Text"},
  {"Display":"Gender", "Type": "Combo", "Selections":"Male,Female"},
]
```

Basically, my question is this: Can I create an android application that would:
1. probably have a "GET" button
2.make the api call to my webapi
3.store the json file inside the phone/app
4.create a form out of this json file
5.display the form, accept input, save the input as json. 
6. have a sync button, and make a post api call to my web service to accept the stored json file.

 As I've said, I just started learning android, and I just want to make sure that learning android would make me "realize" this plan of mine, and make sure I am not wasting any of my time. And can I ask what specific topic in android I should look for to accomplish this? My goal is to make the user able to sync when he/she is online just to get the form layouts, to use and enter data while offline and when he/she is back online, just sync the entered data.
Thanks alot.

Comment: How much you know about android?

Comment: @Joshua I am a complete beginner, that is why I want to know if learning it will serve my purpose/needs.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete beginner, you should first learn about the basic of Android including basic UI and activity life cycle. There are many beginner tutorials online which teaches the basics. After that, you should able to create some basic UI app like simple calculator.

To perform a `GET` and `POST` request, you can either implement yourself or using a library ([Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) (From Google), [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), etc).

For JSON, you should take a look in `JSONObject` if you want to parse it yourself. If you want to use reflection based parsing, you can try [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) (From Google).

These topics should be able to cover what you needed.